# how to undo a kubectl port-forward

Tags: kubernetes

If I forwarded a port using

```
kubectl port-forward mypod 9000:9000
```

How can I undo that so that I can bind port 9000 with another program?
Additionally, how can I test to see what ports are forwarded?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The port is only forwarded while the kubectl process is running, so you can just kill the kubectl process that's forwarding the port. In most cases that'll just mean pressing CTRL+C in the terminal where the port-forward command is running.

Comment: Wow, that is so embarrassing, I didn't realize that it was getting backgrounded from our script, which is why I thought that I would need to delete it or something.  Thanks.

Comment: What if we don't have access to `CTRL+C` because the terminal was closed?

Comment: @alex: hi. what, if I can't use ctrl+c (e.g. Im running all forwards via bash script). How I can stop forwarding inside one .sh? (kubectl forward..>wait N time >"somehow stop forwarding")

Comment: `pkill kubectl -9` to force it

Comment: Is there a way to list all k8s port-forwarding processes?

Comment: `pgrep kubectl` or `ps aux | grep kubectl` are good places to start - https://askubuntu.com/questions/612315/how-do-i-search-for-a-process-by-name-without-using-grep

Comment: I need to kill it in my CI after tests, how would one go about this reliably?

Comment: `In most cases` <<<<<

Answer (score 30):

```
$ ps -ef|grep port-forward

wyyl1      2013886       1  0 02:18 ?        00:00:10 kubectl port-forward svc/prometheus 9090:9090
wyyl1      2253978 2178606  0 07:58 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto port-forward

$ kill -9 2013886
```

Answer (score 28):

If it was launch in the background you can use the `fg` command to access it and then use `ctrl +  C`

Comment: how can i do `kubectl port-forward` in background @Doctor

Comment: @AATHITHRAJENDRAN Simply add **" &"** at the end of your command. For instance : `kubectl port-forward some-pod 9080:3001 &`

Answer (score 20):

If it runs in background, consider using `pkill` to kill processes by their names. Example:

```
pkill -f "port-forward"
```

Answer (score 6):

```
ps aux | grep -i kubectl | grep -v grep | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `pgrep`; this can be dropped into a script and it will kill all PIDs that are port-forwarding:

```
###---
### kill all kubectl port-forward
###---
echo "Dumping all kubectl port-forward PIDs..."
while read -r myPID; do
    kill -9 "$myPID"
done < <(pgrep kubectl)
```

This will usually return only port-forwarding PIDs but realistically, it could be ***any long-running `kubectl` process*** so - be careful.

Answer (score 1):

To kill the specific process the command I use is:

```
ps -aux | grep -i kubectl
```

I then look for the specific port forward for example the output should look like the following:

> User      21625  4.8  0.6 745868 51112 pts/0    Sl   09:29   0:09
> kubectl port-forward -n namespace service/servicename 8898:80

Where 21625 is the process number:

```
kill -9 21625
```

You should then see

> [1]+  Killed                  kubectl port-forward -n namespace
> service/service 8898:80

In the terminal running that process indicating that the process doing the port forward has now been killed.

Answer (score 0):

I use `screen`.

To start (Ansible task):

```yaml
    - name: web port forward for debugging
      vars:
        command: "kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 web-0 8895:1443 --namespace nss &"
      shell:
        cmd: |
          (screen -S "kube-port-forward" -dm {{ command }}) || screen -S "kube-port-forward" -dm '{{ command }}'
```

To stop:

```bash
screen -X -S "kube-port-forward" quit || true
```

Notes:

- this command really works only if I will try the main command without quotes, get error and try with quotes, I dunno why it is so